# value of this constant "UNITS"

Tags: syntax-error

I copied a code source of the internet, and it has a constant "UNITS". What is the value of this constant? I'm trying to find but not found.

see http://graph-studio-next.googlecode.com/svn-history/r169/trunk/baseclasses/pullpin.cpp

```
 m_tDuration = llTotal * UNITS;
```

Comment: Whatever it was declared to be in one of the includes.

Comment: It is 1/10,000,000th of a second (found by searching online). I checked the headers and I could not find a reference to UNITS.

Comment: You don't know whether the code you are reading is C, C++ or C# and you think your worst problem is the value of the constant `UNITS`?

Comment: I was in doubt whether this constant might be a specific function of the C language. I tried to look on the internet, but the word UNITS is quite common.

Answer (score 5):

According to: http://graph-studio-next.googlecode.com/svn/!svn/bc/169/trunk/baseclasses/reftime.h:

```
const LONGLONG NANOSECONDS = (1000000000); // 10 ^ 9
const LONGLONG UNITS = (NANOSECONDS / 100); // 10 ^ 7
```

Comment: Amcap? Isn't that, like, from Win16 days?

Answer (score 1):

`UNITS` is not defined in the source file that you've provided. You can look for it in :

- The includes. This includes `streams.h`, `pullpin.h` and `dxmperf.h`, if `DXMPERF` was defined during compilation or by a file included earlier.
- The compiler command line. It is possible that the value of this `UNITS` is defined as a compile-time constant in the compiler's command line.